# php display output based on drop down from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I know this is already have but we are not getting answer in that post.
i have been having the following problem .I am able to retrieve the data from database and display it in a drop down menu.But i dont know how to use the same drop down list as the input and embed it in a form.My code is as follows.Here project names are retrieved from the database and are displayed in the form of drop down list.Now i need to use the same drop down list in the form(HTML form) which will be used to input data into another table. below is my code

```
 <div id="footer"><?php
    //Include database configuration file
    include('dbConfig.php');

    //Get all state data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM state WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY state_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    ?>
    <select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="">Select state</option>
        <?php
        if($rowCount > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                echo '<option value="'.$row['state_id'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">state not available</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select></div>

if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select district</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['district_id'].'">'.$row['district_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">district not available</option>';
    }
```

Comment: where is you javascript ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `<select>` tag start and end like this :

```
//Display district list
    echo '<select name="test">';
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select district</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['district_id'].'">'.$row['district_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">district not available</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: am able to display dropdown based on drop down i need to show some result from another table in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring your `Select` tag out side of the `if` statement like and at the ending of branching you need to close your select tag. And `if-else` depends on your retrieved value.

```
echo '<select name="test">';
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select district</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['district_id'].'">'.$row['district_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">district not available</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
```