# why this PHP and SQL code with HTML ( drop-down) select item do nothing?

Tags: php, mysql

I write this code to retrieve data from the database table and insert the data in "select" drop-down menu, the below code do nothing and the select list empty, the table contains records. I guess there is something wrong with the code. any help?

```
<select  class = "input100" name="C_Number"  placeholder=" Select Course Number">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <?php 
         $Query = "SELECT * FROM `courses`";
         $CrPost = mysqli_query($db,$Query) Or die($Query);
         $post = mysqli_fetch_array($CrPost,MSQL_ASSOC);
         do { ?>                          
        <option value="<?php echo $post['C_ID'];?>"><?php echo $post['C_Title']; ?></option>
    <?php } while ($post = mysqli_fetch_array($rsPost,MSQL_ASSOC)); ?> 
    </span>  </select>
```

Comment: Almost all of this is wrong, severely. I suggest researching PDO and prepared statements for a start.

Comment: Go learn some HTML basics first maybe? `span` and `i` have no business being inside `select` to begin with.

Comment: You should also make sure that you're using the correct variables and constants. There's no `$rsPost` defined and `MSQL !== MYSQL`. There's too much wrong here. I would sincerely recommend you to do some research and read through a bunch of tutorials about PHP and MySQL.

Comment: A prepared statement is not necessary.

Comment: Lots of places that you could have researched. 
E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36300015/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not use do while ,just use while loop

```
<?php $Query = "SELECT * FROM courses";
         $CrPost = mysqli_query($db,$Query) Or die($Query);
         while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($CrPost)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $post['C_ID'];?>"><?php echo $post['C_Title']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```